# Ways from server-side monolith to microservices

Tags: java, migration, microservices

I work as a working student in a company and my job is to create a guide on how to convert a software monolith to Microservices. The monolith consists of many individual modules on the server side and I am supposed to create this guide on the basis of a single module. This should be done on server side, as client a RichClient is used (no Web-App).

The whole thing is written in Java and a Websphere Application Server with EJBs and Servlets is used.

Now to my question. I am currently not very familiar with software architecture and am not quite aware of the necessary steps. What is clear is that I have to resolve all dependencies of the considering module to further modules, correct? What follows or what has to be assumed before?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] - after doing that you should realize that this question is a little too broad for SO :) - In general the process of migrating a monolith to micro services is neither an easy task nor one where a one-size-fits-all approach would work. You'd need to get some understanding of software architecture in general, on the monolith and microservices in particular, research some techniques on how such a task could be tackled (e.g. have a look here: https://martinfowler.com/articles/break-monolith-into-microservices.html) and then embark on the journey :)

Answer (score 0):

This is very tough to explain here fully , but i can provide you some starting point .
let follow Domain driven architecture for this . assume your monolith application represent a domain . try to divide domain in to sub-domain depending upon functionally , remember each subdomain have its 
1. own ubiquoous language (Language understood by all person involved in project ( technical ,non -technical) )
2. Boundary context --> define boundary of each sub domain 
3. Domain model
4. Aggregate --> Set of entity which should have consistence data (i am not going in to detail of aggregate you can further read )

Basically each sub-domain represent a micro-service.

further you can explore how these microservices are communicated to each other (Synchronous or Asynchronous ) depending on your requirement.